# Weasyprint issue in django app with apache

Tags: django, apache, weasyprint

I have a app with Weasyprint to generate pdf, in local enviroment its no problem, but in a virtual machine server with apache, static folder dont work in pdf files (image and style are not show).

My question is, is there any package that im ignoring or that is required for Weasyprint to work in apache in a production environment?

Besides, I have a production server in google cloud and there it works, with exactly all the same packages.

My list of apt-packages:

- build-essential
- python3-dev
- python3-pip
- python3-cffi
- libcairo2
- libpango1.0-0
- libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0
- libffi-dev
- shared-mime-info

My list of pip packages:

- WeasyPrint

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue. I was wondering if you found the solution to this, it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try switching the static images from JPEG to png. JPEG images seem to be ignored by weasyprint. This worked for  me.

Comment: Hi, it's great that it works for you :)
But, the issue that have also include css and all statics files. My workaroud inserts css and image files from View instead of html template. Regarding images files, I add them in binary with a template tag function. If you have a similar issue, you can try it.  
Thank you, regards.